# Can I use entity framework 6 in windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I'm new to Windows Store apps. I want to use Entity Framework with the combination of SQlite database in my store app. So does this support in store app ? Please correct me if i'm going wrong.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Entity Framework is not supported for Windows Store App.

I believe it is because Windows Store Apps run in WinRT.

However, you can use SQLite with Windows Store Apps without the need for Entity Framework. (As you'd expect)

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework 7 (currently in beta) will support Windows 8.1 Store apps with SQLite